# Wait for one function to return a value before proceeding to the rest of the other function's commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, return

I am combining some animations in jquery with some ajax loading - From function A, I want to be able to call function B to fade out the current content, and once that animation is done, return to run the rest of the code in function A. Is this possible? I'm picturing something like this:

```
function buttonClicked(){
  if(sectionHidden != true){
    hideSection($sectionRef);
  }
  //RUN THE FOLLOWING AFTER HIDE SECTION HAS FINISHED (FUNCTION B)
  loadSection();
}

function hideSection($sectionRef){
  $sectionRef.fadeTo(500,0,function(){
    return someValue;
  });
}
```

Because of some other complexities in my code (multiple functions calling hideSection), I can't call loadSection from hideSection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.fadeTo()` takes a callback parameter which is called when the fade-out is finished. All you have to do is supply it the `loadSection` function. To wit:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    if (!sectionHidden) {
        hideSection($sectionRef, loadSection);
    }
    else {
        loadSection();
    }
}

function hideSection($sectionRef, doneCallback) {
    $sectionRef.fadeTo(500, 0, doneCallback);
}
```

If you don't want to load the section after calling `hideSection()` from another part of your code:

```
function someStuff() {
    //stuff...
   hideSection($superRef); //won't call loadSection()
   //more stuff
}
```

Comment: Sorry - due to a bunch of other complications in the site, I can't handle it this way.

Comment: I lol'ed. Good one. Troll much

Comment: can you explain why? ultimately you will either have to do this (pass a callback) or do some sort of polling mechanism that would be quite ungainly

Comment: ummm... not much of an explanation. if you want to have something happen after `hideSection()` is called, would not the most logical thing be to give that function to `hideSection()`? not every call of `hideSection()` has to call `loadSection` - with my solution you can decide what callback to give it, or give it none at all.

Comment: @PeeHaa: you think mheavers is trolling?

Comment: What does trolling mean?

Comment: Don't know what it is but sounds to me like to [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Anyway saying it is not possible to use callbacks because of whatever is saying you cannot use the steeringwheel of your car for seom reason and asking how to drive. The problem is not the use of callbacks (at least not for the reason given by OP).

Comment: @PeeHaa: oh gotcha, it does sound like that. lets see if mheavers offers any additional explanation then. if not this is all we can do

Comment: Ugh...well, I get what you guys are saying, but I think I would have to post a ton of code to try and explain why I can't do this in a callback. I'll try to restructure my code somehow. Just thought there was a way to pause the rest of a function until a return was received.

Comment: @mheavers: you wanna try going to [cha](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18601/mheavers-chat)t?

Comment: click on the link i put in my comment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, that's not the way javascript works. 
In JS, your code shouldn't block.
Use callbacks instead: in function A call fadeTo and provide the rest of function A in callback. Callback is called when fadeTo completes.

From [jquery fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    $('#book').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
```

EDIT: your code should look something like this...

```
function buttonClicked(){
  if(sectionHidden != true){
    hideSection($sectionRef, function(){
      loadSection();
    });
  }
}

function hideSection($sectionRef, func){
  $sectionRef.fadeTo(500,0,func);
}
```